# Error con URL amigable en PHP

Tags: php, url

Tengo este enlace:

```
<!-- <a href="tienda.php?nombre=lucasTorina">lucasTorino</a> -->
<a href="tienda/lucasTorino">store</a>
```

Y este .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tienda/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ tienda.php?usuario=$1
```

Y me da error 404. El archivo esta en el directorio rais del proyecto:

```
localhost
   |_ tienda
        |_ index.php
        |_ tienda.php
   |_ .htaccess
```

No se si me falta algun dato en el archivo .htaccess o tengo que cambiarlo de directorio. Gracias

Comment: uh, he leído 3 veces la pregunta y no entiendo la duda.

Comment: Entonces te falta la carpeta tienda en la redirección: `RewriteRule ^tienda/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ tienda/tienda.php?usuario=$1`

Comment: Gracias @Triby, funciono!!!